# Error: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: c#, windows-forms, clase

Hola a todos espero puedan ayudarme con lo siguiente:

Estoy tratando de adaptar la siguiente funcion Export Helper.

Lo que quiero es que el usuario tenga la habilidad de exportar a donde el quiera el dgv que le pase a dicha clase, es decir reutilizar la clase en cualquier form donde se invoque dicha clase.

El problema lo tengo en la siguiente linea, me da el siguiente error: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

```
File.WriteAllLines(myPath.ToString(), lines);
```

Si le paso el nombre del formulario con la siguiente linea, si me exporta el dgv, pero requiero exportar cualquier dgv en la ruta que el usuario seleccione:

```
File.WriteAllLines(FormAdjustmentTbl.ruta, lines);
```

Esta es la clase que estoy tratando de adaptar:

```
 internal class ExportHelper
{

    public string myPath { get; set; }
    
        public void Ruta(string path)
    {
        this.myPath = path;
    }

        //return path;
    
    public bool Export(DataGridView dgv)
    {
        bool exported = false;
        

        List<string> lines = new List<string>();
        DataGridViewColumnCollection column = dgv.Columns;
        bool firstDone = false;
        StringBuilder columnLine = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (DataGridViewColumn col in column)
        {
            if (!firstDone)
            {
                columnLine.Append(col.DataPropertyName);
                firstDone = true;
            }
            else
            {
                columnLine.Append("," + col.DataPropertyName);
            }
        }
        lines.Add(columnLine.ToString());

        //data lines
        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgv.Rows)
        {
            StringBuilder dataLine = new StringBuilder();
            firstDone = false;
            foreach (DataGridViewCell cell in row.Cells)
            {
                if (firstDone)
                {
                    dataLine.Append(cell.Value);
                    firstDone = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    dataLine.Append("," + cell.Value);
                }
                lines.Add(dataLine.ToString());
            }

        }

        //File.WriteAllLines(FormAdjustmentTbl.ruta, lines); //Si le paso el nombre del formulario funciona, pero quiero reutilizar esta clase en cualquier formulario donde tenga un dgv
         File.WriteAllLines(myPath.ToString(), lines);
        return exported;
    }
}
```

Y este el codigo del boton exportar:

```
private void btnExport_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SaveFileDialog oSaveFileDialog = new SaveFileDialog();
        if (dgv_AdjTbl.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            SaveFileDialog sfd = new SaveFileDialog();
            sfd.Filter = "CSV (*.csv)|*.csv";
            sfd.FileName = Form.ActiveForm.Text;
            bool fileError = false;
            if (sfd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                if (File.Exists(sfd.FileName))
                {
                    try
                    {
                        File.Delete(sfd.FileName);
                    }
                    catch (IOException ex)
                    {
                        fileError = true;
                        MessageBox.Show("It wasn't possible to write the data to the disk." + ex.Message);
                    }
                }


                if (!fileError)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        new ExportHelper().Ruta(sfd.FileName);
                        new ExportHelper().Export(dgv_AdjTbl);
                        
                       MessageBox.Show("Exportado");
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Error :" + ex.Message);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("No Record To Export !!!", "Info");
        }
    }
```

Como puedo solucionar el error o alguna idea para reutilizar la clase en cualquier form donde se invoque dicha clase, pasandole la ruta que el usuario seleccione?

Espero puedan ayudarme.

Saludos

DS

Comment: Probablemente `myPath` sea null. Asegúrate de que está correctamente asignado.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En la siguientes líneas de tu código está el

```
 new ExportHelper().Ruta(sfd.FileName);
 new ExportHelper().Export(dgv_AdjTbl);
```

En el p rimero: new `ExportHelper().Ruta(...)` creas una instancia de la clase ExportHelper e invocar al metodo Ruta pasandole el Path. Luego de ejecutar esta instrucción el objeto, si bien existe por algún lado ya no puedes referenciarlo.

En el segundo, vuelves a crear una instancia y llamas a Export. Esta instancia es diferente a la anterior por lo tanto no tiene asignada la ruta. Entonces cuando llegas al File.Write, myPath no existe nadie lo creo. Lo que debes hacer es:

1. Crear la instancia y asignarla a una variable: var obj = new ExportHelper()
2. Pasarle la ruta atraves del método Ruta: obj.Ruta(path)
3. Por último llamar al metodo Export.

```
var obj=new ExportHelper();
obj.Ruta(sfd.FileName);
obj.Export(dgv_AdjTbl);
```

Por otro lado, otra alternativa es hacer estática la clase.

Comment: Gracias funciono con tu propuesta, puse un Break Point en las lineas mencionadas para ver las diferencias entre lo que tenia y y tu propuesta de asignar la instancia a la variable obj.